# invalid user.table.column, table.column, or column specification

Tags: oracle

```
CREATE TABLE emp (
  empno NUMBER (10) NOT NULL,
  empname VARCHAR2 (50) NOT NULL,
  mgr VARCHAR2 (10),
  hiredate DATE,
  sal NUMBER (10),
  comm VARCHAR2 (10),
  CONSTRAINT emp_pk PRIMARY KEY (empno)
) ;

DESC emp ;

INSERT ALL
  INTO emp
  (100, 'MARK', 'CXS', hire_date('1999-09-08', 'yyyy/mm/dd'), 8000, 'axw')
  (200, 'peter', 'NULL', hire_date('1996-01-08', 'yyyy/mm/dd'), 9000)
  (300, 'karl', 'NULL', hire_date('1995-05-08', 'yyyy/mm/dd'), 5000, 'AZQ')
  (400, 'MAx', 'NULL', hire_date('1994-04-08', 'yyyy/mm/dd'), 10000, 'DES')
  (500, 'Maggie', 'SAQ', hire_date('1998-06-08', 'yyyy/mm/dd'), 20000, 'QAS')
  SELECT * FROM dual ;
```

Comment: Please explain your question and the problem you are facing.

Comment: Hi there, please look at this guide [how to ask good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 2):

Your [`insert all` syntax](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/INSERT.html#GUID-903F8043-0254-4EE9-ACC1-CB8AC0AF3423) is malformed, you need multiple `into ... values ...` pairs. At the moment it's trying to interpret `100` as a column name, hence the specific error you're seeing.

You also have `hire_date(...)` instead of `to_date(...)`, and you're missing one of the `comm` values; assuming that is supposed to be null:

```
INSERT ALL
  INTO emp (empno, empname, mgr, hiredate, sal, comm)
  VALUES (100, 'MARK', 'CXS', TO_DATE('1999-09-08', 'yyyy-mm-dd'), 8000, 'axw')
  INTO emp (empno, empname, mgr, hiredate, sal, comm)
  VALUES (200, 'peter', NULL, TO_DATE('1996-01-08', 'yyyy-mm-dd'), 9000, null)
  INTO emp (empno, empname, mgr, hiredate, sal, comm)
  VALUES (300, 'karl', NULL, TO_DATE('1995-05-08', 'yyyy-mm-dd'), 5000, 'AZQ')
  INTO emp (empno, empname, mgr, hiredate, sal, comm)
  VALUES (400, 'MAx', NULL, TO_DATE('1994-04-08', 'yyyy-mm-dd'), 10000, 'DES')
  INTO emp (empno, empname, mgr, hiredate, sal, comm)
  VALUES (500, 'Maggie', 'SAQ', TO_DATE('1998-06-08', 'yyyy-mm-dd'), 20000, 'QAS')
SELECT * FROM dual ;

5 rows inserted.
```

I've also changed the stirng literals `'NULL'` to plain nulls, as it seems much more liekly that is what you really intended.

And I've changed the date format masks to use `-` rather than `/`, to match the values. But if you're using fixed values like that it's simpler to use date literals instead, e.g. instead of

```
  INTO emp (empno, empname, mgr, hiredate, sal, comm)
  VALUES (100, 'MARK', 'CXS', TO_DATE('1999-09-08', 'yyyy-mm-dd'), 8000, 'axw')
```

use:

```
  INTO emp (empno, empname, mgr, hiredate, sal, comm)
  VALUES (100, 'MARK', 'CXS', DATE '1999-09-08', 8000, 'axw')
```

Answer (score 1):

The syntax for the INSERT ALL statement in Oracle/PLSQL is:

```
 INSERT ALL
     INTO mytable (column1, column2, column_n) VALUES (expr1, expr2, expr_n)
     INTO mytable (column1, column2, column_n) VALUES (expr1, expr2, expr_n)
      INTO mytable (column1, column2, column_n) VALUES (expr1, expr2, expr_n)

SELECT * FROM dual;
```

So in your case you can use

```
INSERT ALL
  INTO emp (empno, empname, mgr, hiredate, sal, comm)
  VALUES (100, 'MARK', 'CXS', TO_DATE('1999-09-08', 'yyyy-mm-dd'), 8000, 'axw')
  INTO emp (empno, empname, mgr, hiredate, sal, comm)
  VALUES (200, 'peter', NULL, TO_DATE('1996-01-08', 'yyyy-mm-dd'), 9000, null)
  INTO emp (empno, empname, mgr, hiredate, sal, comm)
  VALUES (300, 'karl', NULL, TO_DATE('1995-05-08', 'yyyy-mm-dd'), 5000, 'AZQ')
  INTO emp (empno, empname, mgr, hiredate, sal, comm)
  VALUES (400, 'MAx', NULL, TO_DATE('1994-04-08', 'yyyy-mm-dd'), 10000, 'DES')
  INTO emp (empno, empname, mgr, hiredate, sal, comm)
  VALUES (500, 'Maggie', 'SAQ', TO_DATE('1998-06-08', 'yyyy-mm-dd'), 20000, 'QAS')
SELECT * FROM dual ;
```

Also for any column you want blank/no value just put NULL if you include this as 'NULL' it will be considered as text NULL.